# Counting the occurence in the regular time spans in R

Tags: r, dplyr, time, series

I have a data frame with year, site and pointer.

```
year<-c(1200, 1201, 1202, 1204)
site_a<-c("0", "1", "1", "0")
site_b<-c("0", "0", "1", "0")
site_c<-c("0", "-1", "1", "0")
df<-data.frame(year,site_a, site_b, site_c)
lw2<-pivot_longer(df, cols=site_a:site_c, names_to="site", values_to="pointer")
```

I want to count the number of pointer (1 and -1) in two years spans like:

```
intval<-2
lw2%>%
  group_by(site, pointer)%>%
  filter(pointer == 1 | pointer == -1)%>%
  group_by(pointer, add = TRUE)%>%
  summarize(startDate = seq(from=1200, to=1204, by=2),
            endDate = startDate + intval-1, 
            frequency = n())
```

As a result I am getting the same, total number of pointers for each time spans,

| site | pointer | startDate | endDate | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| site_a | 1 | 1200 | 1201 | 2 |
| site_a | 1 | 1202 | 1203 | 2 |
| site_a | 1 | 1204 | 1205 | 2 |

while I want to get number of pointers for each time span:

| site | pointer | startDate | endDate | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| site_a | 1 | 1200 | 1201 | 1 |
| site_a | 1 | 1202 | 1203 | 1 |
| site_a | 1 | 1204 | 1205 | 0 |

Do you have suggestions on how to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

lw2 %>%
  right_join(expand(., year = 1200:1205, site)) %>%
  group_by(year%/%2, site) %>%
  summarise(startDate = min(year),
            endDate = max(year),
            frequency = sum(pointer != 0, na.rm = T),
            .groups = 'drop') %>%
  select(-1)

#> # A tibble: 9 × 4
#>   site   startDate endDate frequency
#>   <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>     <int>
#> 1 site_a      1200    1201         1
#> 2 site_b      1200    1201         0
#> 3 site_c      1200    1201         1
#> 4 site_a      1202    1203         1
#> 5 site_b      1202    1203         1
#> 6 site_c      1202    1203         1
#> 7 site_a      1204    1205         0
#> 8 site_b      1204    1205         0
#> 9 site_c      1204    1205         0
```

Comment: It works! I have just modified it to count separately 1 and -1 pointers: `frequency = sum(pointer == 1, na.rm = T),` and `frequency = sum(pointer == -1, na.rm = T),`

Comment: It also works with: `lw2%>%
  group_by(interval = cut(year, breaks = c(1200:1204)))%>%
  filter(pointer == 1 | pointer == -1)%>%
  group_by(site,  pointer, add = TRUE)%>%
  summarize(frequency = n())`